# Error: The name 'Task' does not exist in the current context, while following unity firebase storage documentation

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-storage

The point is, I tried to follow firebase documentation for using storage on unity. Specifically for uploading image file.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/unity/upload-files

Here's my code

```
// Get a reference to the storage service, using the default Firebase App
Firebase.Storage.FirebaseStorage storage = Firebase.Storage.FirebaseStorage.DefaultInstance;

// Create a storage reference from our storage service
Firebase.Storage.StorageReference storage_ref = storage.GetReferenceFromUrl("gs://AR-Festival-2018.appspot.com");


// Data in memory
byte[] custom_bytes = SaveLoad.imageTexture[activeIndex].EncodeToPNG();

// Create a reference to the file you want to upload
Firebase.Storage.StorageReference rivers_ref = storage_ref.Child("images/rivers.jpg");

// Upload the file to the path "images/rivers.jpg"
rivers_ref.PutBytesAsync(custom_bytes)
  .ContinueWith ((Task<StorageMetadata> task) => {
    if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled) {
        Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString());
        // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
    } else {
        // Metadata contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
        Firebase.Storage.StorageMetadata metadata = task.Result;
        string download_url = metadata.DownloadUrl.ToString();
        Debug.Log("Finished uploading...");
        Debug.Log("download url = " + download_url);
    }
});
```

simply copy pasting it cause a result in which the term 'Task' and 'StorageMetadata' didn't exist with message:
The name 'Task' does not exist in the current context

[image]

Did I miss something? Is there any unity package I need to include in order for the Task to work?
I'm using unity 2017.3.1 with c#

UPDATE:

In unity Log, I get this error,

Assets/AR Part/Script/Gallery.cs(218,20): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Task' could not be found. Are you missing `System.Threading.Tasks' using directive?

Comment: By default unity uses .NET 3.5. Task was only introduced in .NET 4.0 if i'm not wrong. You can use an experimental version of .NET 4.6 by changing it in player settings. [Link](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2017/07/11/introducing-unity-2017/#runtime)

Comment: I already tried it, but after restarting I still get this error:
Assets/AR Part/Script/Gallery.cs(218,20): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Task' could not be found. Are you missing `System.Threading.Tasks' using directive?

Comment: Hint: Are you missing `System.Threading.Tasks` using directive?